# StringIndexOutOfBounds when removing adjacent duplicate letters

Tags: java, string, recursion

Here is my code:

```
 public static String removeAdjDuplicates(String s) {
     if(s == "" || s == null || s.isEmpty())
         return s;

     if(s.length() < 2) 
         return s;

     if(s.charAt(0) != s.charAt(1))
          s = s.charAt(0) + removeAdjDuplicates(s.substring(1));

     if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(1)) //line 37
         return removeAdjDuplicates(s.substring(2));

     return s;
 }
```

With the input string "ull", I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at GFG.removeAdjDuplicates(File.java:37)
    at GFG.main(File.java:16)
```

I read and tried answers given to similar questions, but I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: The string is only guaranteed to have 2 characters, so `s.substring(2)` may fail.

Comment: You're also mutating your input data, which makes me feel queasy - you're not going to want to overwrite that.

Comment: replace `s == ""` with `s.equals("")`

Comment: In fact, you can replace that whole condition with `"".equals(s)`

Comment: @Jobin and @pushkin No,can be removed entirely. It's already covered by `s.isEmpty()`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen:  The null check is still valuable.

Comment: @Makoto Yeah, only need the null check and the call to `isEmpty()`

Comment: @Jobin nobody is suggesting removing the null check. The comparison to empty string however is obsolete since `isEmpty()` was introduced in Java 6.

Comment: i tried all the above suggestions. Its still not working.

If i give the string "ll". It works fine.

With strings like pull: It gives:
Run Time Error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
 at GFG.removeAdjDuplicates(File.java:37)
 at GFG.removeAdjDuplicates(File.java:35)
 at GFG.main(File.java:16)`

Comment: Folks - this code is complete enough to dervive a full working reproduction of the OP's issue.  It also includes the error message *and* the specific location of the error.  This does *not* deserve to be closed with the "Why isn't this working" reason.

Comment: Consider scanning a string and using a `StringBuilder` to only collect a character from the string if it's different from the previous character. Special-case strings shorter than 2 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you Try to pass this string **"ull"** to the method the last letter in the String should be the letter "u" because you use this

```
if(s.charAt(0) != s.charAt(1))
          s = s.charAt(0) + removeAdjDuplicates(s.substring(1));
```

as you dont return the String back like the other conditions in the method it will continue to the next condition at line 37 
and u have only one letter while the condition checking the first and the second characters ... there is no second letter so you get this error .. so the solution is to return s like this

```
if(s.charAt(0) != s.charAt(1)){
          s = s.charAt(0) + removeAdjDuplicates(s.substring(1));
         return s;
     }
```

Comment: oh god thanks! I think @dasblinkenlight was also trying to say the same thing but I was just too naive to understand it. Thank you for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the exception that you get, `removeAdjDuplicates` returns an empty string, invalidating all indexes past zero.

Although your code performs length checking at the top, it also performs this assignment when the two initial characters are different:

```
s = s.charAt(0) + removeAdjDuplicates(s.substring(1));
```

This means that `s` can become a one-character string if `removeAdjDuplicates` returns an empty string.

Comment: Thank you i understand. But for my i/p string "ull" 
`s = s.charAt(0) + removeAdjDuplicates(s.substring(1));`
this line gives "ll" which is of length two,
then why do i still get the error?

Comment: @sanvj For input `ull`, the result of `s = s.charAt(0) + removeAdjDuplicates(s.substring(1));` is `u`, not `ll`, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the source of the error is sufficiently explained by [@dasblinkenlight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41477110/3558960).

Although not clearly stated in the question, it looks like you're trying to remove adjacent duplicate letters recursively (one of your comments mentions that you would expect output `s` for input `geegs`).

Here's an alternative way to do it:

```
    while(!s.equals(s = s.replaceAll("(.)\\1", "")));
```

It uses a regular expression to match and remove duplicate characters, and the while loop keeps executing this until the string is no longer being modified by the operation.

Answer (score 0):

You should simplify your code:

```java
public static String removeAdjDuplicates(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() < 2)
        return s;

    if (s.charAt(0) != s.charAt(1))
        return s.charAt(0) + removeAdjDuplicates(s.substring(1));

    return removeAdjDuplicates(s.substring(2));
}
```

## Changes

- The first two `if` statements do the same thing (`return s;`) and can be combined into one. Some of the conditions are redundant and can be eliminated.
- The third `if` statement should immediately `return` instead of continuing into the fourth if statement (or you can instead change the fourth `if` statement into an `else`), because `removedAdjDuplicates` can return an empty `String` making `s` a length-one `String` when the fourth `if` is expecting at least a length-two `String`.
- The fourth `if` can be eliminated because if `(s.charAt(0) != s.charAt(1))` failed in the third `if`, then the only alternative is that `(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(1))`, so the check for that isn't necessary.