# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException while trying to encrypt a read file, and write the encrypted phrase to a different file

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to code a program that will read in text from a file that the user specifies, will then encrypt the text using the Caesar Cipher, and finally write the encrypted phrase to a different file. I'll also want to eventually have it do the reverse, where it reads encrypted text and decrypts it, but one step at a time.

```
package CaeserCipher1;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class CaeserCipher1 {
public static final String ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ";

//Method to pull the plaintext of a file, followed by how far you want to shift plaintext to the right.
public static String encrypt(String plainText, int shiftKey) {
    String cipherText ="";
    for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {
        int charPosition = ALPHABET.indexOf(plainText.charAt(i));
        int keyVal = (shiftKey + charPosition) % 26;
        char replaceVal = ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
        cipherText += replaceVal;
    }
    return cipherText;
}
    //Method to pull the encrypted text of a file, followed by how far you want to shift the text to the left.
   public static String decrypt(String cipherText, int shiftKey)
    {
        String plainText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < cipherText.length(); i++)
        {
            int charPosition = ALPHABET.indexOf(cipherText.charAt(i));
            int keyVal = (charPosition - shiftKey) % 26;
            if (keyVal < 0)
            {
                keyVal = ALPHABET.length() + keyVal;
            }
            char replaceVal = ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
            plainText += replaceVal;
        }
        return plainText;
    }
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt a file? ");
       String choice;
       choice = keyboard.next();

       if (choice.equals("encrypt")) {
           System.out.println("What is the name of the file you would like to encrypt?: ");
           String readFile = "";
           readFile = keyboard.next();
           System.out.println("What is the name of the file you would like to write the encrypted phrase to?: ");
           String writeFile = "";
           writeFile = keyboard.next();

           FileReader fileReader =
                    new FileReader(readFile);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                    new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            FileWriter fileWriter =
                    new FileWriter(writeFile);
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =
                    new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

            String message = "";
            while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) !=" ") {
                bufferedWriter.write(encrypt(message, 8));
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
            }
       }
   }
}
```

The error I receive:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String 
index out of range: 25
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at CaeserCipher1.CaeserCipher1.encrypt(CaeserCipher1.java:15)
    at CaeserCipher1.CaeserCipher1.main(CaeserCipher1.java:63)
```

I understand the general idea behind the out of bounds exception by reading other peoples problems, but from reading the answers on other problems I can't find an issue in my own code. I've read in other peoples issues where they use <= in their if loop instead of <, I've seen the one where people are tying to use the substring form, etc.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: The file being read from will only use capital letters, thus the reason ALPHABET only has capital letters.

Comment: check that the keyVal >= 0 && keyVal < cipherText.length(), same goes for keyVal used on the plainText

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StringIndexOutOfBounds when removing adjacent duplicate letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477037/stringindexoutofbounds-when-removing-adjacent-duplicate-letters)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the letter `X` into `ALPHABET`.  Please carefully read over your code before posting questions...

Your code also doesn't handle any characters other than the ones in `ALPHABET`, so you're going to end up with a whole bunch of `H`'s (for a shift of 8) in the ciphertext that won't decode properly.

Comment: Fair enough on the first point.
As for the second - the file being read from will only use capital letters, that's my fault for not specifying that.